# Showing proper solarized colors in emacs + iterm2

Tags: macos, emacs

I see the following instead of the solarized theme on Ethan's site:

[image: emacs theme]

I tried many different ways (xterm-256colors, recompiling the different solarized themes), but none of them seem to show the correct colors.

Please help! Thanks so much!

Comment: Did you make sure there are no other places where you have defined changes to your colors?

Comment: Which Emacs version do you use?  Which Solarized theme implementation do you use?  Is iTerm2 using a Solarized theme, too?

Comment: Yes, iTerm2 is using a solarized theme too. I don't think I've defined changes to colors anywhere...

I use emacs24 and i'm currently using color-theme-solarized, installed using the package manager.

Comment: Emacs 24 has built-in themes now. Use solarized-theme instead of color-theme-solarized. But more importantly, what looks wrong to you? That screenshot looks like solarized to me.

Comment: @Ista It may be solarized, but fontification is definitely broken in the screenshot.  Keywords and function declarations are apparently not fontified, though they definitely should be.  However, that may no be related to color themes at all.  We'll need to see the configuration this screenshot was taken for.

Comment: @lunaryorn Right, my point is that it is not at all clear that the problem has anything to do with the solarized theme. Paul Woidke, can you show us what that screen looks like with a different theme?

Comment: @Ista Agreed. Though Paul Woidke is not really the right person to ask for a screenshot :)  user2108690 has to help us here…

Comment: it says "unable to find theme file for solarized-theme"
Where should I find the configuration file?
here's my emacs if i do M-x load-theme tango
http://postimage.org/image/7dgd19l6z/